# How to import a WSDL definition wit use="encoded" RPC's

Tags: java, wsdl, wsimport

I want to `wsimport` the following link `https://ilias.ice-karlsruhe.de/webservice/soap/server.php?wsdl` but this doesn't work since there are some `use="encoded"` definitions in there.

If I start to `wsimport` this file I get the following errors:

```
[ERROR] "Use of SOAP Encoding is not supported.
SOAP extension element on line 1.162 in http://www.ilias.de/test42/webservice/so
ap/server.php?wsdl has use="encoded" 

Failed to parse the WSDL.
```

How can I get my Java source and class files using `wsimport` for this file?

Can you give me a little tutorial if you answer with some kind of `"Axis"`?

Comment: Which version of Axis?

Comment: @KeerthiRamanathan This error comes up with wsimport, but Axis 1.4.

Comment: Can you try webservices wizard in eclipse using Axis 1.4?